# Laravel 5.2 Login Doesn't Work

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have a Laravel app in my web server. I wanted to develop it in my local server, so I pushed it to my git server first, then clone to my local server.
After that, first I installed composer and run migrations.

When I open the app from browser, I see login screen. If I use wrong password, It returns an error, however if I enter my correct password, it redirects to login page again.

At first, I thought it is happening because of my local configurations. Then, I copied my web server configuration to another folder. If I use old database config, it works, on the other hand if I change database settings and migrate again, face with same problem.

PS: After every new setup, I generate a new key. I'm not sure if I should change anything else. 
I changed session driver from file to cookie, but didn't work.
I also removed all storage/sessions folder.

How can I fix that problem?

Edit:
My Codes (Routes, Controller and Config):
http://laravel.io/bin/MkG7z

Comment: _When I open the app from browser, I see login screen. If I use wrong password, It returns an error, however if I enter my correct password, it redirects to mainpage._ Then what's the problem with this?

Comment: I mean, it redirects to login page again.

Comment: Can you provide any error logs so it can be a bit clearer?

Comment: post the view/controller code

Comment: And show us your session.php config file, i believe the probleme is there also check your routes file , if you have a route groupe with the web  middleware try to remove it

Comment: @Sab Did you check your database connection ? Provide some error log that could be helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: http://laravel.io/bin/MkG7z
You can see all the codes in routes, controller and session.php
There is nothing special in view, it just prints variable.

Comment: Check your folder permissions, the last time this happened to me the cause was this. Check this answer for a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30746378/4584870